# Google Places API - Returning invalid street numbers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

If I search for `500 Buckingham Place, Eight Mile Plains` the Google Places API returns `500 Buckingham Place, Eight Mile Plains, Queensland, Australia` with the place id `Ej41MDAgQnVja2luZ2hhbSBQbGFjZSwgRWlnaHQgTWlsZSBQbGFpbnMsIFF1ZWVuc2xhbmQsIEF1c3RyYWxpYQ`. If I then do a details call on that place id it returns `Buckingham Pl, Eight Mile Plains QLD 4113, Australia`.

This can be replicated on the Google Maps website at https://www.google.com.au/maps/search/500+Buckingham+Place+Eight+Mile+Plains. The place returned will just be `Buckingham Pl, Eight Mile Plains QLD 4113, Australia`.

Can I get Google Places API to only return search results for actual street numbers?

**EDIT**
The call I am doing is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=500%20Buckingham%20Place%2C%20Eight%20Mile%20Plains&types=address

Comment: How are you doing the search?  Are you using the web service or the Google Maps Javascript API v3 Places Library?

Comment: @geocodezip I have added an API call example

Comment: i don't understand the problem. What do you will like to put in and what to get as answer exacly?

Comment: @TomKarachristos It is returning a result from the autocomplete api for a street number that does not exist. I do not want it to return results in this case. In my example Buckingham Place only goes up to a street number of 52, but you can search for anything number above that and the autocomplete api will still return it as a valid place. This happens for all streets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [google map api doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#reverse-geocoding-by-location):

> Addresses are returned in the order of best to least matches.
>   Generally, the more exact address is the most prominent result, as it
>   is in this case. Note that we return different types of addresses,
>   from the most specific street address to less specific political
>   entities such as neighborhoods, cities, counties, states, etc.

So the problem is that when you add a street number that doesn't exist a no perfect matche(s) return. Here is how to find if a answer is not perfect match:

Again in [google doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results)

> partial_match indicates that the geocoder did not return an exact
>   match for the original request, though it was able to match part of
>   the requested address.

If you do some test you will see that when a street number don't exist(or the address is not valid or you don't give enough info for a unique address) it return a variable partial_match:true and one or more close matches, like the picture.
[image]

I made a simple example with autocomplete and geocoder: http://jsfiddle.net/TomKarachristos/qLyrj38d/,
it return "not a valid result" when partial_match is true

```
if (results[0].partial_match) {
  htmlContent = "not a valid result";
  } else {
  [...]
}
```

Note: The data of google map maybe will not be 100% accurate.

Comment: I am using the autocomplete api (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) not the geocode api. I can't see the partial_match with any request from the autcomplete api

Comment: The autocomplete API provides function getPlace() who gives more information for a place than for a map address, so you must use it together with geocoder to take what you want. See again the fiddle, I update it.

Comment: So it seems there is no way to not show an invalid address in the autocomplete. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you want you can try make a autocomplete from the start using jquery ui, have a lot of work but with this way you have full control. Here an example  http://rjshade.com/2012/03/27/Google-Maps-autocomplete-with-jQuery-UI/